# Grub still looks wided and with low resolution

Tags: grub2, display-resolution

I already adjusted the grub resolution, set it to 1920x1080 and applied the changes, but it still looks low resolution.

I've also tried with Grub Customizer but it doesn't work either. I aplied a theme but it looks wided and with low resolution too.

What can I do?

Comment: To start with you can give the most basic info that is missing from the question. what version of Ubuntu? Saying you applied a theme but not what theme is another example of not giving all info. Make and model of the monitor may also help.

Comment: I'm using the latest, and a 1080p monitor (a Samsung C24FG70)

Comment: There is no such thing as the latest, that can be a few versions. It seems you do not want any help.